# CMake compilation error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but cyglto_plugin.dll not found

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cmake, clion

I just installed CLion using Cygwin as the Environment. When CLion runs the first test (with "Hello World!"), it gets the following compilation error:

```
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
1
c++: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but cyglto_plugin.dll not found
compilation terminated.
```

Could someone please help me resolve this? Being my first time using CLion, I do not know how to proceed.